# Удаление елемента списка после выполнения цикла

Tags: python

Есть такая задача:
ОТЧЕТ ПО СЧЕТАМ
Напишите программу, которая проходит по всем операциям в файле bank.txt, а после выводит все счета и баланс каждого счета.

Данные нужно вывести в следующем формате:
Счет1 Баланс1;Счет2 Баланс2;Счет N; Баланс N.
То есть счета между собой разделены точкой с запятой, а каждый счет по отдельности содержит свой номер и баланс, разделенные пробелом.

Счета нужно выводить в порядке увеличения баланса (см. пример отчета ниже).
В файле есть счет 000 — это внутренний счет банка, его выводить не надо:

000;123;200
123;456;100
456;789;200
789;123;500

Пример отчета (на основе данных из условия):
789 -300;456 -100;123 600

Код ниже считает сумму по каждому счету и формирует список, который сортируется последним циклом. Отсортировать нужно без использования sort, lambda или функций, только циклами и условиями. Последний цикл находит минимальную сумму и записывает ее в новый список. Затем нужно этот элемент удалить и я не знаю как это сделать. После удаления ищем следующую минимальную сумму и тд.
Если удалить его после строки
outsort.append(minn)
то сортировка не получится.
Как удалить элемент правильно, для реализации описанной логики?

```
from sys import argv
check = argv[1]
a = open("bank.txt", "r", encoding="utf8").readlines()
listcheck = []
for x in a:
    if not x[:x.find(";")] in listcheck:
        listcheck.append(x[:x.find(";")])
    if not x[x.find(";") + 1:x.find(";", x.find(";") + 1)] in listcheck:
        listcheck.append(x[x.find(";") + 1:x.find(";", x.find(";") + 1)])
#print(listcheck)
summ = 0
out = []
for y in listcheck:
    if y == "000":
        continue
    for x in a:
        endout = x.find(";")
        endinc = x.find(";", endout + 1)

        outcome = x[:endout]
        income = x[endout + 1:endinc]
        money = x[endinc + 1:]
        if y == outcome:
            summ -= int(money)
        if y == income:
            summ += int(money)
    out.append(str(y) + " " + str(summ))
    summ = 0
print(out)

q = 1
minn = "999 99999999"
outsort = []
while q <= len(out):
    for i, x in enumerate(out):
        if int(minn[4:]) > int(x[4:]):
            minn = x
    outsort.append(minn)
    q += 1

print(outsort)
```

Comment: Переделать цикл по индексам а не по элементам коллекции for i in range(len(out)): тогда при изменении коллекции цикл будет корректно повторяться

Comment: Pavlo Khyzhniak,  если я удаляю хоть по индексам, хоть по значениям - алгоритм ломается. Это и есть проблема.
Но удалить элемент нужно после завершения цикла, а не во время цикла.
Если в этом алгоритме удалять во время цикла то мы не найдем минимальное значение постольку, поскольку после удаления пропустим следующий элемент.

Comment: Вот пример:
out = ['123 100', '456 -100', '789 -300', '777 500']

q = 1
minn = "999 99999999"
i_minn = 0
outsort = []
while q <= len(out):
    for i in range(len(out)):
        if int(minn[4:]) > int(out[i][4:]):
            minn = out[i]
            i_minn = i
    outsort.append(minn)
    del out[i_minn]
    q += 1

print(outsort)

Строка    del out[i_minn]  все ломает. Как удалить минимальное значение из out после каждого завершения for ?

Comment: попробуй это q = 1
minn = "999 99999999"
outsort = []
cnt = len(out)
index = 0
while q <= cnt:

    while index < cnt:
        if int(minn[4:]) > int(out[index][4:]):
            minn = out[index]
        index+=1
    outsort.append(minn)
    out.remove(out[index])#delete
    cnt-=1
    q += 1

Comment: Разобрался, в циклах сортировки minn нужно объявлять в теле while.
Оно не менялось после for  и оставалось самым минимальным числом, меньше следующего искомого минимального. Поэтому последнее просто не находилось. Много времени потратил, а оказалось мелочь.